# Loading CSV to phpmyadmin on localhost ( long time )

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin, localhost

I want to import some data from *.csv file on localhost, but it seems like it is suspended. Im using ubuntu 14.04, apache 2.4, php 5.6, mysql 5.6.
**My question** is how to speed up this process? Do I have wrong configurations? On other web hosting this loading took 15 seconds ( file 2MB ). On my host looks like infinite loop.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

may be your csv file is very big. One of these method may help you

1. increase upload_max_filesize in php.ini
2. try import zipped csv file
3. split into sub csv files. Then try import one by one

Comment: Ad.1 I increased to 512MB, reloaded apache2. And still nothing.